# Which event in a MudBlazor MudSelect is called when selection is changed and how would it be implemented?

Tags: c#, blazor, .net-6.0, mudblazor

I'm using MudBlazor and implemented a MudSelect component following the documentation.

However, I'm trying to get the selected value from the MudSelect when a selection has been made but unsure which event to call. Tried a few such as SelectedValuesChanged but nothing is firing in my code block when the selection has been updated.

Using a standard HTML select I would just call @onchange and then write a method for the event. This doesn't work in MudBlazor.

Here is my MudSelect

```
<MudSelect T="Stage" Label="Stage" Variant="Variant.Filled" AnchorOrigin="Origin.BottomCenter">
    <MudSelectItem Value="@(new Stage("Stage 1"))" />
    <MudSelectItem Value="@(new Stage("Stage 2"))" />
    <MudSelectItem Value="@(new Stage("Stage 3"))" />
    <MudSelectItem Value="@(new Stage("Stage 4"))" />
    <MudSelectItem Value="@(new Stage("Stage 5"))" />
</MudSelect>
```

Here's the @code block

```
public class Stage
{
    public Stage(string stageName)
    {
        StageName = stageName;
    }

    public readonly string StageName;

    public override bool Equals(object o)
    {
        var other = o as Stage;
        return other?.StageName == StageName;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode() => StageName?.GetHashCode() ?? 0;

    public override string ToString() => StageName;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `ValueChanged` event callback which is fired when the Value property changes.

**Implementation:**

```razor
<MudSelect T="Stage" 
        ToStringFunc="@converter"
        ValueChanged="OnValueChanged" 
        Label="Stage" 
        Variant="Variant.Filled" 
        AnchorOrigin="Origin.BottomCenter">
    <MudSelectItem Value="@(new Stage("Stage 1"))" />
    <MudSelectItem Value="@(new Stage("Stage 2"))" />
    <MudSelectItem Value="@(new Stage("Stage 3"))" />
    <MudSelectItem Value="@(new Stage("Stage 4"))" />
    <MudSelectItem Value="@(new Stage("Stage 5"))" />
</MudSelect>

@if(selectedStage is not null)
{
    <br/>
    <MudAlert Severity="Severity.Info">@(selectedStage.StageName) was selected</MudAlert>
}

@code {
    private Stage selectedStage {get; set;}
    readonly Func<Stage, string> converter = p => p.StageName;

    private void OnValueChanged(Stage selected)
    {
        selectedStage = selected;
        // Do other stuff
    }

    public class Stage
    {
        public Stage(string stageName)
        {
            StageName = stageName;
        }

        public readonly string StageName;

        public override bool Equals(object o)
        {
            var other = o as Stage;
            return other?.StageName == StageName;
        }

        public override int GetHashCode() => StageName?.GetHashCode() ?? 0;

        public override string ToString() => StageName;
    }
}
```

**Demo:**
https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/cOwGFYQavuiuzWnd

**Output:**
[image: Output for MudSelect using ValueChanged event]

Comment: This is great, I just want to use this in a simpler way and get the selected value, I don't need to bind it to a class like this. How can I do that?

Comment: @niico you can use the '@bind-Value' attribute, but that way you can't use the ValueChanged event.